# Regex For Every Second Letter In Individual words

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to implement a regex query that can select every second letter (per word) so that I can action the returned values.

I have attempted the following using [This sandbox](https://regexr.com/)  but nothing has been successful.

`\w([A-Za-z])` ,`\w(\w)` , `\w{1}(\w){1}`

What would the correct regex expression be to select every second letter of each word.

As an example:

```
H[i] t[h]e[r]e s[t]a[c]k[o]v[e]r[f]l[o]w
```

Comment: Can you use another solution? Or is it necessary to use regex?

Comment: @HassanImam I've completed a similar task using code yes, with a basic kind of `for word { for i{if i%2==0 then word[i].dSomething() `  program. I'm interested in how it would be done in regex now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply select all character that comes after a character.

```
[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z])
```

[image]

```js
const str = "Hi there stackoverflow";
const result = [...str.matchAll(/[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z])/g)].map((arr) => arr[1]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: May I say, beautiful answer!

Answer (score 0):

This simplest solution would be to match for \w and ignore the every other match from the result

Comment: Welcome to SO!. While this might result in a solution, without code to illustrate it is more of a comment. If you include sample code, snippets if you can, you're more likely to get upvotes and accepted answers